# No timestamps are set when files are restored from the recycle bin in Google Drive V3 API

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I am currently dealing with the timestamps in the Google Drive V3 Api. I noticed, that when I recover a deleted file from trash, no timestamp is set. Also the `modifiedTime` and the `modifiedByMeTime` are not updated.

How I get the time of recovery?

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: What time are you referring exactly? The one you [untrashed](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/untrash) the document? I think that is not possible to recover from the API, you can get the time it was trashed though. Is that useful for your case? Maybe it could be a good candidate for a [Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/support#missing_features) to the Drive API.

Comment: Hi, Yes. I want exactly the time it was untrashed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer here is that the metadata of the file does not have any attribute to indicate the recovery time. Which it is quite unfortunate for your case. Let me offer you some workaround that you may want to use.

#### Workaround

You cannot have that field from the metadata. But you can introduce it yourself through [adding custom properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties)

Use the [`update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) endpoint to add a new property:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID>?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "properties": {
    "untrashedDate": "2021-02-12"
  }
}
```

---

This is what I believe a very feasible request to have from the API. If you would like to see implemented you can reach to the [Missing Features](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features) section and file a bug to see if they consider adding this feature.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this idea, but unfortunately it does not help. I want to find files that have been restored by the user and not those that I have deleted myself. I have already created a feature request